# Is there a milliseconds equivalent for second(), minute(), hour(), etc. in Hive SQL? If not, how can I extract just the milliseconds from a date?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have data like this:

```
2019-12-11 23:38:26.583
```

And I want to receive back this:

```
583
```

i.e. just the milliseconds part.

In Hive SQL, there are functions like `second()`, `hour()`, `minute()`, etc. that let you extract these elements very easily, but I don't see one for `millisecond()`. And I tried it and it doesn't do anything, i.e. it doesn't exist. How can I accomplish this then?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_format`:

```
select date_format('2019-12-11 23:38:26.583', 'SSS');
```

Note that this returns string type. If you want int type, you can cast accordingly:

```
select cast(date_format('2019-12-11 23:38:26.583', 'SSS') as int);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work if there is a leading 0. For example ".022" gets converted to "22" which throws everything off

Comment: @emberfly then don't cast to int. Use the first code.

Answer (score 0):

One more method using regexp_extract:

```
select regexp_extract('2019-12-11 23:38:26.022', '\\.(\\d+)$',1);
```

Result:

```
022
```